# Chartkick Timeline undefined method `each_pair' for#< Array:... > in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I'm having an issue with a Chartkick Timeline chart in Rails 4.
When the page loads this error is thrown:

"undefined method `each_pair' for#< Array:... >"

in the Chartkick code as shown below;

```
 def chartkick_deep_merge(hash_a, hash_b)
  hash_a = hash_a.dup
  hash_b.each_pair do |k, v|
    tv = hash_a[k]
    hash_a[k] = tv.is_a?(Hash) && v.is_a?(Hash) ? tv.deep_merge(v) : v
  end
  hash_a
end
```

I have attempted various iterations of the code using to_json, as_json, @events.each do ..., @events.map... attempted
    timeline("chart-1", "phase_masters_phase_time_path") 
that points to
    render json: Events.select(:id, :event_types, :starttime, :endtime).where(project_masters_id: params[:proj_id], phase_masters_id: params[:id])

The variables appear to be being set correctly as can be seen in hash_b

```
hash_a  
{:width=>"400px", :height=>"400px", :colors=>["#B9D3EE", "#9FB6CD", "#A2CD5A", "#6E8B3D", "#FFB90F", "#E3A869"]}

hash_b  
[[#<Events id: 1, event_types: "Estimating", starttime: "2015-10-05 11:15:00", endtime: "2015-10-13 21:15:00">], [#<Events id: 2, event_types: "Roll Forming", starttime: "2015-09-09 11:00:01", endtime: "2015-09-16 18:29:59">], [#<Events id: 7, event_types: "Magest On Site", starttime: "2015-09-25 11:00:01", endtime: "2015-09-25 18:29:59">]]

view:
 <div id = "chart-1"> </div>
   <%= 
    timeline("chart-1", @events.map { |evnt| [evnt] } )
   %>


controller:
@events = Events.select(:id, :event_types, :starttime, :endtime).where(project_masters_id: params[:proj_id], phase_masters_id: params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json {render json: @events}
        end
```

Any help with getting this running would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your passing an array of `Events` to the method `timeline`, that method expects an array of triplets (of type array).

I'm not sure I'm reading your code right but it seems like the call to `timeline` could instead be something like

`timeline("chart-1", @events.map { |evnt| [evnt.types, evnt.starttime, evnt.endtime] })`

Comment: Thank you for the response;

Comment: Thank you for the response; I made the change suggested 

<script> var Chartkick = {"language": "en"}; </script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %> 
  
<div class="small-10 small-centered columns", align="center">
  <div class="row">
    <h4 class="subheader">Phase Timeline</h4>
      <div id="chart-1">
          <%= timeline("chart-1", @events.map { |evnt| [evnt.event_types, evnt.starttime, evnt.endtime] }) %>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
But when i run it the following error is thrown; 
"undefined method `each_pair' for #<Array:0x000000087a0d20> "

Comment: Local Variables

hash_a 
{:width=>"400px", :height=>"400px", :colors=>["#B9D3EE", "#9FB6CD", "#A2CD5A", "#6E8B3D", "#FFB90F", "#E3A869"]}
hash_b 
[["Roll Forming", Wed, 09 Dec 2015 07:15:00 EST -05:00, Mon, 14 Dec 2015 16:30:00 EST -05:00]]

Comment: I got rid of the the <div id="chart-1"> and "chart-1 in the timeline and things started happening. Still working with it but its better than it was

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i got me onto the right track, appreciate it.

Comment: @mjjor happy to help :)